# How to expand cards with react-toolbox

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-toolbox

Does react-toolbox card component (http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/card) offer any expandable option similar to material-ui cards? (http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it doesn't. You can add an onClick handler on the container component that changes the className of the container element with a different height (and include a CSS transition for height so it animates). It's pretty straightforward to do so. Let me know if you need more assistance.